# csrf() doesn't work with WebTestClient in non-reactive code

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing, spring-security, csrf

I want to use a WebTestClient for integration tests in spring boot on non-reactive code.
Endpoint which I want to use has csrf protection provided by spring security.
When I use test like below:

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class Test {
    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient webTestClient;

    @Test
    public void test1() {
        webTestClient
                .mutateWith(SecurityMockServerConfigurers.csrf())
                .post()
                .uri("endpoint")
                .bodyValue(value)
                .exchange()
                .expectStatus().isOk();
    }
}
```

I get an exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.springframework.web.server.adapter.WebHttpHandlerBuilder.filters(java.util.function.Consumer)" because "httpHandlerBuilder" is null
```

The exception occurres just when I want to use `.mutateWith()` method.
If I use WebTestClient without `.mutateWith()` on not protected route by csrf all works.

I do not want to use mockMvc.